# Poster author added me as coauthor after abstract was submitted. Can I include it on CV?

Tags: conference, cv, authorship, poster

Poster author added me as coauthor after its abstract has been submitted to a conference. As a result, on the conference website I'm not listed as an coauthor, but my name is on the actual poster.

Assuming that it's not possible to update poster authorship info on the conference website, should I still list this poster on my CV, or would it just create confusion or misunderstanding?

Comment: I do not list any posters or talks on my CV if I was not the first author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A poster of which you're not the first author is such a minor thing I wouldn't worry about it (even if it is listed on the conference website).  I don't have a huge publication list but still only include posters *I* presented (aand only at major conferences).  They don't have anything like the CV impact of a peer-reviewed paper.

Either:

- You were accidentally omitted and should be included. In this case the author should contact the conference organisers (but it's probably too late).
- Or your contribution was rather minor -- perhaps it only became apparent that your work made it onto the poster at all at the last minute.  In this case while you're named as an author it's closer to an acknowledgement in practice.

Listing it as a publication, if the title can be searched for but you're not named, doesn't seem like a good idea.  Realistically no one is ever going to look.  But if you just happen to come up against someone who's interested in something very specific about the poster that you don't normally do, it isn't going to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't support posters any longer for my personal academic career, but there are eminent examples of major breakthroughs which were presented as posters, for instance Gruntzig seminal invention of angioplasty (in particular, look at [Gruentzig's Poster Exhibit at 1976 AHA](http://www.ptca.org/archive/bios/gruentzig.html)), so we cannot discard their value altogether.

Regarding your question, I think you can add the poster details on your CV. 
The best thing is however to also write an email to the publisher of the proceedings (putting in cc the corresponding author) to have the author list amended (this can be done in the online version). Finally, try to also obtain the final version of the poster (eg in pdf), and possibly a photo taken of the actual poster when and where it was hanged.